# Scan qr code in view pager android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, qr-code, zxing

i already developed demos with zxing library and many other libraries but I want integration in fragment view pager.

Can anyone give me suggest which library or some modification will work in open QR scanner in view pager?

[image]

i want to impliment this desgin, so please help me

Comment: hoping to have more answer then "-" voting

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried google "fragment view pager"?

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fragment+viewpager